# Hint for form/page initialisation

Tags: .net, blazor, single-page-application

I need a hint: when you develop an SPA with Blazor or another framework/library how do you do form initialisation?  Do you make a single request to a REST service that returns a JSON with the initial state of the application or do you make several individual requests for each specific piece of data?

For example: I have a form to enter a new book, when I initialize it, I need to fill in some fields and controls like genre list or language list (user can select from a drop down list without needing to type it in).

Thanks, best regards.

Comment: Your lists [such a genre] and separate entities so treat each one separately.  You may need to get the same key set [such as Country] for several different forms.  Think SRP - "Single Responsibility Principle".